# mod_rewrite on parent and subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I ran into some strange behaviour using `mod_rewrite` under Apache. Here's how the current `RewriteRules` look:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/collections/(.*)/(.*)/?$ bootstrap.php?controller=category&user=$1&collection=$2&category=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/collections/(.*)/?$ bootstrap.php?controller=collection&user=$1&collection=$2 [L]
```

My expectations of the above rules is that accessing a URL such as `domain.com/BenM/collections/0/1/` should take me to the `category` controller, while `domain.com/BenM/collections/0/` should take me to the `collection` controller.

At the moment, both URL structures rewrite to `bootstrap.php?controller=category...`.

My understanding was that if the `[L]` flag is specified, Apache looks no further and performs the rewrite.

Could anyone point in the right direction here, as I just cannot beat this... What should the rewrites look like to achieve the functionality I explained above?

Comment: the first rule match both urls, change .*  to .+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with greediness-related issues. Also, you probably want a length of at least one, and you almost certainly don't want slashes in your params.

Potential solution:

```
^([^/]+)/collections/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
^([^/]+)/collections/([^/]+)/?$
```